# Problems with Activity and filtered ListView

Tags: java, android

I've been searching how to make `ListView` can be filtered within `SearchView`.
But now I'm trying to find out how to connect to the Activity based on the top result.

I've tried with this code but still get to the same Activity but different search result.

```
package com.rahmadewi30.android.kamus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class Search extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    ListView lvItem;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    SearchView inputSearch;
    String[] tumbuhan = new String[]{
        "Lumut Tanduk","Lumut Hati","Lumut Daun" ,"Semanggi", "Bakau",
        "Paku Kawat", "Nanas","Pisang","Mangga"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        lvItem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItem);
        inputSearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.editCari);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Search.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, tumbuhan);

        inputSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        lvItem.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent l = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityLumut.class);
                    startActivityForResult(l, 0);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent l = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityLumutHati.class);
                    startActivityForResult(l, 1);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    Intent l = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityLumutDaun.class);
                    startActivityForResult(l, 2);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Clicking on the top item (`if (position == 0) {` ...) will always start the same activity, no matter what the item (`view`) actually is/contains.

Comment: Yes, that is! can you help me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this one :

```
lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    if (position == 0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), YourActivityName.class); 
         startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
    } else if (position == 1) { 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Youractivty2.class); 
       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
    } else if (position == 2) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), YourActivity3.class); 
         startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
     } else if (position == 3) { 
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), YourActivity4.class); 
          startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
      } 
  });
```

Comment: It's just the same, you only change the intent variables. When I filter search the third list when I click it it's just go to the first unfiltered list activities.